# React-router-dom 6.4 RouterProvider router={router} usage

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Is there a way to use `<router />` in place of `router`?

```
RouterProvider router={router}
RouterProvider router={<router />}
```

Comment: Please clarify what any actual issue is and the overall use case you are trying to accomplish. AFAIK, no, the `RouterProvider` `router` prop takes the returned data router created by one of the router creators, not any JSX.

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning react. The training is with react-router-dom 5.2 

It was gathering some data into a class. then export within "return" in a function.
Then render with
ReactDOM.render(<App />)

I try to do this with react-router-dom 6.4.


Because there is a character limit in the comment,  I am sending next comment.


I think I need to find better way to understand. Thanks.

App class is like below comment. I've cutted some lines beacuse of character limit.

Comment: export class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
    this.setAlert = this.setAlert.bind(this);
    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
    this.state = {
     loading: false,
     users: []}}
     render() {
  return (
 <BrowserRouter>                  
   <Alert alert = {this.state.alert}/>
   <Routes>
   <Route  path='/' element={
   <Route path='user/:login' element={<UserDetails params={this.params} getUser={this.getUser} user={this.state.user}/>}  />              
   </Routes>                       
 </BrowserRouter>)}}
export default App;

Comment: You don't need to use the new Data APIs provided by RRDv6.4, the regular routers still work. If you are having an issue with some specific code then please edit your post to include a [mcve].